# Display "root" node in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

How to display the "root" in TreeView?

Do I need to create  a a special HierarchicalDataTemplate for the root?

This is my code:

```
<TreeView Margin="0,0,15,0" Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">           
  <TreeView.Resources>           
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
      <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Data}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

```cs
Node node0 = new Node("Root");
Node node1 = new Node("Node1-1");
Node node12 = new Node("Node1-2");
Node node21 = new Node("Node2-1");
Node node22 = new Node("Node2-2");
Node node31 = new Node("Node3-1");
Node node9 = new Node("Node9");
node12.Children.Add(node21);
node12.Children.Add(node22);
node22.Children.Add(node31);
node1.Children.Add(node9);

node0.Children.Add(node1);
node0.Children.Add(node12);
treeView1.DataContext = node0;

public class Node
{      
    List<Node> children;
    public List<Node> Children
    {
        get { return children; }
        set { children = value; }
    }       

    string data;
    public string Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public Node()
    {
        children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public Node(string data)
        : this()
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a root you need to specify an `ItemsSource` with only one item in it, the root node, it has to be an `IEnumerable`, the node itself cannot be the source.

e.g.

```cs
treeView.ItemsSource = new [] { rootNode };
```

Comment: I don't understand,  specify an ItemsSource with only one item in it?

Comment: Something like: `treeView.ItemsSource = new List<Node>() { rootNode };`

Answer (score 3):

Use a converter:

```
public class RootTreeviewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new object[] { value };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootNode,Converter={StaticResource rootConv}}" />
```